# Autologin after frontend registration

Tags: users, registration

I have a frontend user account registration form and I d like to auto login the user automatically after the account creation.

So the user can choose a subscription plan and pay immediately after, without having to enter his login and password a second time.

I added the parameter 'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' but it does not work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my god I lost half the day on a syntax error !!

My general.php file had the line with true in quotes :

```
'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => 'true',
```

The correct line to have the parameter work is:

```
'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
```